# How can I open NERDTree at left side?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I am new to vim and trying to use NERDTree. Well, I think I succeeded to install it but every time I open NERDTree, it opens at the right part of the window as shown below. I want it to open at the left as default but I don't know how. How can I open NERDTree at the left side of the window by default?

I tried to put `let g:NERDTreeWinPos = "LEFT"` or `let g:NERDTreeWinPos = "left"` in `vimrc` file but it didn't work.

[image]

For more details my .vimrc code looks like this
I use ultimate vim.'

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required

let g:NERDTreeWinPos = "LEFT"

set runtimepath+=~/.vim_runtime
set showcmd
set number

source ~/.vim_runtime/vimrcs/basic.vim
source ~/.vim_runtime/vimrcs/filetypes.vim
source ~/.vim_runtime/vimrcs/plugins_config.vim
source ~/.vim_runtime/vimrcs/extended.vim

try
source ~/.vim_runtime/my_configs.vim
catch
endtry
```

Comment: Sorry for the image but image uploading process have changed and I can't find the way to show directly

Comment: Can you edit your question to also include your `vimrc`?

Comment: vimrc added thank you!! @Rafael

Comment: It must be in lowercase : `let g:NERDTreeWinPos = "left"` and not `LEFT`

Comment: Nerdtree is on the left per default. So I guess your variable gets overwritten. try running that in a running vim instance: `let g:NERDTreeWinPos`, what is the output?

Answer (score 0):

In case this has not been answered, access the `~/.vim_runtime/vimrcs/plugins_config.vim` file and change the NERDTree position in that file.